# Application crash when pressing image in GridView (Android)

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclicklistener

i Have this GridView i'm using to show images.
In the bottom line i want to press an image and that my view in another activity will get the image.

This is the code i'm using in my OnItemClickListener-

```
        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View bg = (View)findViewById(R.id.background);
            bg.setBackgroundResource(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

            finish();

        }
    });

    grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

The reason my application crash is because the View(bg) return as null. how can i fix it ? and make it right ?
I really like someone to help me with this one.. Thanks !

Comment: Not Sure may be you are not getting the view with the id please check whether (View)findViewById(R.id.background); returns null or not

Comment: You are right ! i do get the view as null. why its happening, because the view isn't in my presented Activity ? and how can i change it?

Comment: @AmirFoghel : in which layout you have `R.id.background `view ?

Comment: if it is not in your present activity layout, you can inflate the layout and get the your desired view.

Comment: @AmirFoghel : have you tried it `View bg = (View)Your_main_Activiy.this.findViewById(R.id.background);`

Comment: yes, View bg = (View)Your_main_Activiy.this.findViewById(R.id.background); i get an error says: No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope

Comment: @AmirFoghel : ohh!!, what is name of your main Activity use your main Activity name in place of `Your_main_Activiy`

Comment: LOL my friend.. i did it - i didn't used "Your_main_Activiy" instead of the real name..

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have `R.id.background` in your `activity_main.xml`, you have to assign that layout to your activity at first with `setContentView(...)` like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
  grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

  gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
          View bg = (View)findViewById(R.id.background);
          bg.setBackgroundResource(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

          finish();
      }
  });
}
```

Your `findViewById()` needs that content view.
That's the default usage of a [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) with an `ImageAdapter`.

Note: With this solution, you should also have your `GridView` with id `grid_view` in the same layout.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for you help.
finally i just passed the source of the image and set it onStart in my other view.
Thanks anyway!